# How to register an agent with launchd

Tags: macos, launchd

I’m unable to schedule a periodic launch with `launchctl`/`launchd` on OS  X (Leopard). Basically, I’m unable to find a step-by-step list of instructions on the web and the intuitive approach doesn’t work.

The `sync.plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>net.madrat.utils.sync</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>rsync</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>-ar</string>
            <string>/path/to/folder/</string>
            <string>/path/to/backup/</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>7200</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I’ve put this script inside the path `~/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Next, I’ve *registered* the script using

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/sync.plist
```

Finally, to test that it works, I *started* the job:

```
 launchctl start net.madrat.utils.sync
```

– Nothing happened. Manually executing the `rsync` command in the terminal yields the expected result.

I’m fairly sure that the job was registered correctly because if I try to start a non-existing job, I get an error message (which I *didn’t* get in the above command).

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/) is a good GUI tool to manage launchd. The project appears to be unsupported now... but it definitely still works on 10.5.x.

But to your specific problem... have you tried

```
sudo launchctl list
```

This will tell you if the .plist is firing correctly. It'll return 1 if the daemon is not lauching , and a '0' if it is successful. Maybe look for that.

Whenever I see a '1' it's usually because I've put the script in the wrong place, made a typo or have set permissions incorrectly.

Also.... reboot often .. I've seen

```
launchctl start
```

not be effective where a reboot  was ..

Also, in looking at your question closer....why not just put that rsync code into a bash script...and stick it in `/usr/bin/`..... Then you could just `chmod+x` that file....and simplify your .plist to fire that script whenever you like ....

Comment: Thanks, putting the command into an extra shell file and launching *that* did the trick. It’s a very unsatisfactory solution though … why doesn’t invoking the command directly work? By the way, `launchctl list` *did* display 1, but only after I started the agent manually using `launchctl start`.

Comment: I am not positive, but I think the launchd .plist files are really just intended for defining 'launch-on-demand' criteria for daemons...Perhaps it was not sure what to do with the arguments you had passed in <key>ProgramArguments</key>.

Answer (score 12):

**Long answer:**

It is hard to work with launchd without understanding some basic principles. So it is likely you won't find any step-by-step instruction, it has so much capabilities. A good move is to head for the getting started guide on the ADC: http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html

You can also read the man pages for `launchd`, `launchctl` and the .plist files syntax, `launchd.plist`.

There's a frequent misunderstanding on where to put your agent or deamon, so let me push some info about it here:

- If your job needs to run even when no users are logged in, put it in /Library/LaunchDaemons.
- If it is only useful when users are logged in, put it in /Library/LaunchAgents, or in the personal LaunchAgents directories of specific users (~/Library/LaunchAgents).
- Do not put your job in /System/Library, which is reserved for system-provided daemons.

> ```
> ~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
> /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
> /Library/LaunchDaemons         System wide daemons provided by the administrator.
> /System/Library/LaunchAgents   Mac OS X Per-user agents.
> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  Mac OS X System wide daemons.
> ```

**Short answer:**

The name of your plist file may be wrong, can't test right now but I would have set it to  `net.madrat.utils.sync.plist`. It may be also useful to first `unload` your deamon before loading it if you edited the file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However: (1) I’ve already read all the documents you linked above, and several more. Nowhere does it actually say how to launch an agent. (At least, I didn’t find it anywhere.) That would be fine, *if* my intuitive approach were working. (2) Changing the file name doesn’t work either. :-( (3) some of the information are outdated. For example, they suggest the command `launchd bash` for debugging – but this doesn’t work on Leopard (`launchd` cannot be launched directly).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: You're welcome: :) @Skylarking gets some interesting points: did you check the file's premission? Or used the sudo command? I also had to reboot sometimes for launchctl to work properly.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find documentation that this is actually standard behavior, but it seems that launchd requires absolute paths in plist files. So try `/usr/bin/rsync` instead. Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

try this, my scripts work without using the program part, just program args...

replace

```
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>rsync</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>-ar</string>
        <string>/path/to/folder/</string>
        <string>/path/to/backup/</string>
    </array>
```

with

```
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>rsync</string>
        <string>-ar</string>
        <string>/path/to/folder/</string>
        <string>/path/to/backup/</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this keys to your plist file

```
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one wrong thing in your .plist file, and one dodgy thing (each of these points has been touched upon in earlier answers; I'm bringing them together here).

You'd be better writing:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/usr/local/bin/rsync</string>
  <string>-ar</string>
  <string>/path/to/folder/</string>
  <string>/path/to/backup/</string>
</array>
```

The first argument in the `ProgramArguments` array is the program to be executed – you'd omitted this.  If the `Program` key is omitted, then it defaults to the first argument of `ProgramArguments`; it's probably wise to specify this only once.

Because you omitted this first argument, your .plist *will* have invoked rsync (through being named in `Program`), but rsync's 'first argument' would have been `/path/to/folder`, and not `-ar` (the running program will have been very briefly visible in `ps` output, before it exited with an error, but named as `-ar`, which is the content of the zeroth argument).

You don't *have* to include the path to `rsync`, but in this sort of context, it's probably prudent to do so, to avoid having to rely on the `PATH` being set appropriately.

The documentation for this is in `launchd.plist(5)`.  Note that that manpage stresses that the value of the `ProgramArguments` key is passed to `execvp(3)`.  It's the `execvp` manpage that explains about the PATH searching.